# How can I set the title of non-main-windows in an NSDocument application?

Tags: nswindow, nsdocument, nswindowcontroller

I am working on a document-based OSX application, with master-detail style windows. I understand how to open additional windows, to display additional information, by using `-makeWindowControllers` and adding extra window controllers, but I can't set the title of the new windows. I have tried using `-setTitle` and `-windowTitleForDocumentDisplayName` in both `Document.m` and in my sub-classed window controller class, but I can't get the window title to change.

How do I change the title of non-main-windows, which have a sub-classed window controller, in an NSDocument based application?

**EDIT:** I know there are some suggestions on SO about using an IBOutlet to the window to do this, but surely the window controller has a reference to its window anyway, right?