# How do I override -windowTitleForDocumentDisplayName?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nswindow, nsdocument, nswindowcontroller

In the Mac Developer Reference for `windowTitleForDocumentDisplayName`, [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindowController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindowController/windowTitleForDocumentDisplayName:), it suggests that a window controller can override this method,

> to customize the window title. For example, a CAD application could append “-Top” or “-Side,” depending on the view displayed by the window.

But I can't find any example code showing exactly how to do this. When I override this method in my custom window controller class, it doesn't seem to get called, when I create a new instance of my window controller class. I've been searching the web for a couple of days to find information about this method, but there is hardly any info out there. Much of it is really old - my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27013061/how-can-i-set-the-title-of-non-main-windows-in-an-nsdocument-application) is one of the only recent pages linked to by Google.

Help please!

Answer (score 0):

This method appears to be called only when the NSWindowController's `document` is actually set to an [`NSDocument`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSDocument_Class/) instance.

Answer (score 0):

in your NSWindowController subclass:

```
- (NSString *)windowTitleForDocumentDisplayName:(NSString *)displayName
{
    NSString *newName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Test", displayName];

    return newName;
}
```

NOTE: this is called from NSDocumentController's openUntitledDocumentAndDisplay: method, so the input displayName will be some variant of "Untitled".